# How do I create this trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables: `table1` and `table2`. I have a trigger in `table1` that inserts the current row into `table2` based on some conditions. If the row gets inserted into `table2`, I want to delete that row from `table1`. Now in Oracle, it seems we cannot delete the current row from the trigger in `table1` itself.

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly does not work? Why shouldn't it be possible to delete rows?

Answer (score 1):

A row level trigger on a table can manipulate the data of the updated rows. It cannot perform additional dml on the table itself (select, insert, delete).

A possible solution is to create a view on table1 with an `INSTEAD OF` trigger that deletes from table1 *and perform all insert/update/delete statements on the view instead of the table*

Example: when test_table.name is updated to 'KOEN', then row itself will be deleted. *This example shows just an `ON UPDATE` trigger but it can be done for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE*:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id   NUMBER
    GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY
    CONSTRAINT test_table_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
);

CREATE VIEW test_table_v AS
  SELECT
    id,
    name
    FROM
    test_table;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_table_v_bu
    INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON test_table_v
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  -- do your stuff on the other table.
  IF :NEW.NAME = 'KOEN' THEN
    DELETE FROM test_table WHERE id = :NEW.ID;
  END IF;
END;
/

koen>INSERT INTO test_table ( name ) VALUES ( 'JIM' );

1 row inserted.

koen>select * from test_table;

   ID    NAME 
_____ _______ 
    3 JIM     

koen>update test_table_v set name= 'KOEN';

1 row updated.

stapp_dev--SAMPLEAPPS>select * from test_table;

no rows selected
koen>
```

Comment: i think you did not get my question. Suppose we insert a student into table1. I have a trigger that calculates some things and decides if he has passed the exam or not. If he passes, he goes into table2. Now if he goes into table 2, that student's row should be deleted from table 1. The deleting part is whats not working.

Comment: On the other hand, I think that you (Skydark) didn't get Koen's answer.

Comment: @Skydark I updated my answer (italic text). In this solution, all dml (update/insert/delete) will be done on the view not on the base table. Updating a table and then in a trigger deleting the current row is not possible. So you update the view and the INSTEAD OF trigger can perform what you need (update table2, update table1, delete from table1 - whatever you want).